# Cannot download an InfoPath form template

Tags: 2010, infopath

I am replacing a colleage for the support of a SharePoint 2010 intranet.
I need to modify a InfoPath form.
I get an error message when I try to download a copy of the form template from the intranet.
The message informs me the file can not be open.
I have checked my permissions on the form template and I have got the "Full Control" permission level on it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

is the form being used to inject data into a sharepoint list?  or maybe is it meant to be filled out and saved into a SP forms library?

if either of those two scenarios are happening (rather than the form being filled out and saved externally or printed) then you may need to find the library where the form is saved, access the Library ribbon and click on the Infopath button to open the form in edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

What you find on the SharePoint site is the **published** form. In order to change that form, you need to get a copy of the **original** form, not the published version. The original form will be stored somewhere in your company's file share, not necessarily in SharePoint.

Comment: But I can download a copy of another published form